# Run tests from JUnit base class before tests from subclass

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, junit

For a certain kind of test, I have an abstract super class and subclasses which extend this super class. In the super class, I have one test called `test0IfDirectoryCopied` that is always executed when a sub class is tested. It checks whether the resources set in the subclass is correctly setup.

While this is very nice, unfortunately, this `test0IfDirectoryCopied` gets executed only after all the tests form the subclasses have run. As it serves as a sort of precondition, it would be most helpful if it was executed before any of the sub class tests.

Additional info: The subclass and super class are both annotated with `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`, and `test0IfDirectoryCopied` is lexicographically the smallest entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of JUnit have `Assume`.  Basically if an assumption fails, the test is ignored.

If you put this in the `@Before` and it fails, the every test in the test class will be ignored.

```
import static org.junit.Assume.*;
public class TestMySubClass extends TestSuperClass{

    @Before
    public void makesureDirectoryCopied(){

       assumeTrue( directoryCopied());
   }

   ...
```

Where `directoryCopied()` is like your `test0ifDirectoryCopied` except it returns `true` or `false` instead of throwing an exception.

Since this is pure JUnit, no additional dependencies are needed.

[See Assume tutorial](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assumptions-with-assume) for more info

Answer (score 1):

If it is a precondition You could try to annotate the precondition with @before annotation.
But still:

You could try Junit.contrib to do it. 
https://github.com/junit-team/junit.contrib/tree/master/assumes

You can try to define a test suite and run it one after another

You can try using testng and @dependson annotation

Comment: `@before` is executed before every test method, which is not what I want. `@beforeClass` does not work because at that point, my resources are not yet setup. 
Moreover, I want `test0IfDirectoryCopied` to be executed as a normal test, which both of the above do not do.

I don't see how I could use TestSuites to get the desired behavior.

I do not want to add a dependency to testng.

Junit.contrib's `@Assumes` does what I want. However, I also do not want to add a dependency to Junit.contrib.

Comment: Well, when using testng I could declare a default constructor in the subclass, so that the tests from parent run before my child class. Does it work also for junit?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details of `test0IfDirectoryCopied` I think implementing a [rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) that can be added to each test class would be the best solution. This allows you to get rid of a test class hierarchy, too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works with JUnit out of the box. What I really want to have is a lexicographical test execution order across my whole test class hierarchy (although also other strategies could be defined, for example to always execute tests in the base class first). I found the easiest way to achieve this is by implementing my own TestClassRunner:

```
public class LexicographicalTestOrderRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public LexicographicalTestOrderRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<FrameworkMethod> getChildren() {
        List<FrameworkMethod> children = super.getChildren();
        Collections.sort(children, new Comparator<FrameworkMethod>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(FrameworkMethod o1, FrameworkMethod o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });

        return children;
    }
}
```

It is enough to specify this runner in my base class, using:

```
@RunWith(LexicographicalTestOrderRunner.class)
```

As an additional benefit of this, I can now remove all the `@FixMethodOrder` annotations in the sub classes.